# Unable to click action selection box using webdriver

Tags: webdriver

I am unable to click on the action selection box given below.

I need to click on the "include" action selection box.

Here is my code

```
WebElement divElement1 = driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-pagingListBox itemContainer0"));
divElement1.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-nodeListBoxItemWidget-actionSelectionBox")).click();
```

HTML code:-

```
<div class="PagingListBox-itemContainer" id="gwt-debug-pagingListBox-itemContainer1" style="height: 23px;">
<div id="gwt-debug-pagingListBox-item-1" class="C1TWYC-nf-e C1TWYC-nf-a PagingListBox-item">
<div id="gwt-debug-nodeListBoxItemWidget-actionSelectionBox" class="C1TWYC-Ie-a" style="">
<div id="gwt-debug-actionSelectionBox-status" class="statusPanel goog-inline-block" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
   <div class="gwt-Label"></div>
</div>
<div id="gwt-debug-actionSelectionBox-menu" class="menuPanel goog-inline-block">
   <div class="C1TWYC-Ie-e">include</div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="PagingListBox-itemContainer" id="gwt-debug-pagingListBox-itemContainer1" style="height: 23px;">
<div id="gwt-debug-pagingListBox-item-1" class="C1TWYC-nf-e C1TWYC-nf-a PagingListBox-item">

Comment: <div class="PagingListBox-itemContainer" id="gwt-debug-pagingListBox-itemContainer1" style="height: 23px;">
<div id="gwt-debug-pagingListBox-item-1" class="C1TWYC-nf-e C1TWYC-nf-a PagingListBox-item">
<div id="gwt-debug-nodeListBoxItemWidget-actionSelectionBox" class="C1TWYC-Ie-a" style="">
<div id="gwt-debug-actionSelectionBox-status" class="statusPanel goog-inline-block" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="gwt-Label"></div>
</div> 
<div id="gwt-debug-actionSelectionBox-menu" class="menuPanel goog-inline-block">
<div class="C1TWYC-Ie-e">include</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gwt-debug-actionSelectionBox-status")).click();`

?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code contains id as `gwt-debug-pagingListBox-itemContainer1` while you are using `gwt-debug-pagingListBox-itemContainer0` in your code.

Another thing, if your require id `gwt-debug-nodeListBoxItemWidget-actionSelectionBox` is unique on page then you can click it directly by using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-debug-nodeListBoxItemWidget-actionSelectionBox")).click();
```

Once you confirm that your locator is fine then you can also use JavascriptExecutor. replace locator according to your convenience

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("YOUR XPATH"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```